# The values output are all correct except for the Count on the first index

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int[] number = new int[50];
        int index = 0;
        boolean swap = true;
        int temp;


        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        do
        {
            int input = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (input != -999)
                number[index++] = input;
            else
                break;
        } while (index != 0);

        int[] newNumbers = new int[index];
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            newNumbers[i] = number[i];


        System.out.println("\nNumbers\t" + "Occurances");
        goBack: for (int i = index - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int n = index - 1; n > i; n--)
                if (newNumbers[n] == newNumbers[i])
                    continue goBack;


            int count = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < index; n++)
                if (newNumbers[n] == newNumbers[i])
                    count++;

            for(int s=0; s < newNumbers.length-1; s++){
                for(int j=1; j < newNumbers.length-s; j++){
                   if(newNumbers[j-1] > newNumbers[j]){
                       temp=newNumbers[j-1];
                       newNumbers[j-1] = newNumbers[j];
                       newNumbers[j] = temp;
                   }
               }
           }
            System.out.println( newNumbers[i] + "  " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is intended to take the input through the keyboard scanner. The entered integers are compared and a list of distinct elements of the array number[] will be sorted and printed. However, The list of input contains multiples of some elements. The elements that are repeated are marked in a count. The final output should be a list of the distinct array elements (no duplicates) in order from greatest to least with their respective counts.

The input is as follows: -12, 3, -12, 4, 1, 1, -12, 1, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, -12
when the sort is through and this prints, the index 4 has a count of four when it should have a count of 2. I have tried selection, bubble, and exchange sort algorithms all with similar results. Any advice would be greatly appreciated :) .

Comment: You have neglected to mention what your code is meant to do :)

Comment: If I interpret the last paragraph of this post correctly I think he is trying to sort the `newNumbers` array. So unless this is an exercise for educational purposes why not use `Arrays.sort()`

Comment: Hah, my apologies. The code is intended to take the input through the keyboard scanner. The entered integers are compared and a list of distinct elements of the array number[] will be sorted and printed. However, The list of input contains multiples of some elements. The elements that are repeated are marked in a count. The final output should be a list of the distinct array elements (no duplicates) in order from greatest to least with their respective counts.

Comment: My professor has forbidden us from using Arrays.sort(). If only it were that easy.

Comment: I don't have time to look into to your code in detail right now, but I'll give you some pointers as to what I would do. 1) You need some sort of sorting your numbers, preferably [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) as it yields the occurrence count as well (though it might not be applicable in this case) 2) Make the sorting into its own thing, don't try to do everything at once. The general flow of your program should be something like `sortInput -> findOccurrenceCount -> sortOccurrenceCount -> printYourData`. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: What is the benefit of first loop within `goBack`?

Comment: @ atomman Thank you for your input. I will re-evaluate the flow. I am trying to do it all at once, so that may very well be my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps , though can be a better solution than this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers  = new int[50] ;
    int index = 0;
    int temp;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // get the user input
    System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    do {
        int input = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (input != -999)
            numbers[index++] = input;
        else
            break;
    } while (index != 0);
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("\nNumbers\t" + "Occurances");
    // create a new array and store the user input
    int[]  newNumbers = new int[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        newNumbers[i] = numbers[i];
    // sort the array
    for (int s = 0; s < newNumbers.length - 1; s++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < newNumbers.length - s; j++) {
            if (newNumbers[j - 1] < newNumbers[j]) {
                temp = newNumbers[j - 1];
                newNumbers[j - 1] = newNumbers[j];
                newNumbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newNumbers));
    int count = 1;
    int prevElement = 0;
    if (newNumbers.length > 0) {
        prevElement = newNumbers[0];
    }
     // print the results
    for (int x = 1; x < newNumbers.length; x++) {
        if (newNumbers[x] == prevElement) {
            count++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(prevElement + " occurs " + count + "times");
            prevElement = newNumbers[x];
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(prevElement + " occurs " + count + "times");

}
```

Comment: @ Noob UnChained I tried to build this code in JCreator and it gave me this: "error: method toString in class Object cannot be applied to given types;" I know this can happen if I there is something else with the name Arrays in the program, but that is not the case.

Comment: Add `import java.util.Arrays;` at the top .

Comment: I had the proper imports, I was unaware that I should comment that line out. I'm still getting used to the little nuances and conventions of programming. It worked like a charm :) Thank you very much @ Noob UnChained

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you really want shorter one ::

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer number[] = new Integer[50];
        int index = 0;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        System.out.println(" ");
        do
        {
            int input = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (input != -999)
                number[index++] = input;
            else
                break;
        } while (index != 0);

        List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(number);
        for(Integer n: asList){
            if(n != null)
            System.out.println(n + " occurance " + Collections.frequency(asList,n));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Tushar Trivedi Thank you very much for your response. I was restricted from using lists. Had I been able to use lists and the array sort in the API this would have been easy. Thanks again!

Comment: Where is the sorting algo ?